# Given a function $g$ such that $g(3) = 2$ and $g'(3) = 3$. If $P(x)=g^2(x)=(g(x))^2$ then $P'(3)=$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given a function $g$ such that $g(3) = 2$ and $g'(3) = 3$. If $P(x)=g^2(x)=(g(x))^2$ then $P'(3)=$

Is this the right way to solve this?
I tried to do the chain rule on $(g(x))^2$ and got $P'(3)=2(g(3))g'(3)$ and this equals $12$, I know the answer is $12$ because I have the answer key I just want to know if what I did makes sense or if it was just a coincidence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right way to write :

$P^{'}(x)=2g(x)g^{'}(x)$

Putting $x=3$ we get ....

The answer is correct though.